# MongoDB unnormalized data and the change stream

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an application that most of the collections in it are heavily read then write, so I demoralized the data in them, and now I need to handle the normalization of  the data, for some collections I used jobs in order to sync the data but that not good enough as for some cases I need the data to be normalized in real-time,

for example:

let's say I have orders collections and users collection.

orders have the user email(for search)

```
{
   _id:ObjectId(),
   user_email:'test@email.email'
   ....
}
```

now whenever I am changing the user email in users I want to change it in orders as well.

so I find that MongoDB has [change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)  which looks pretty awesome feature, I have played with it a bit and it gives me the results I need to update my other collections, my question is does anyone use it in production? can I trust on this stream to be always set the update data to update the other collections? how does it affect the DB performance if I have many streams open? also, I use the nodejs MongoDB driver does it has any effect

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked yet with `change stream` but these cases are very common and can be easily solved by building more normalized schema
Normalization form 1 says among the others "don't repeat data" - so you will save the email in the `users` collection only
`orders` collection won't have the `email` field but will have `user_id` for joining with `users` collection with `lookup` command for joining collections
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: i cant normalize the data because i need to search and sort by this field. if i use lookup to do it that mean i will have to scan and load all the the users collection into memory and then do full scan( i wont be able to index as its a temp collection) for search and sort.

Comment: In most of cases you *never* need to load the whole collection into memory.   
Mongo handles it for you: it builds execution plan for the query, uses indices and performs very efficiently.   
Consider `lookup` as a regular join in RDBMS - it doesn't load all the data to the memory without a reason and takes care of configuration params for RAM limits

Comment: only the first phase in the aggregation framework  and only few actions in this phase (like $match and $sort) are using the real collations and indexes . after that its builds every thing on the memory

Comment: 1. If the result collection after the lookup won't fit to memory, mongo will use the disk - it won't blow the ram or affect other processes in the server. By default mongo uses 50% of available ram and you can configure it with `cacheSizeGB` setting. 2. You need to look on the execution plan - and add the proper index on `email` field so joined collection will use an index. 3. If normalizing is a real problem, so go and use `triggers` (mongo uses `change streams` for it) :) 4. Maybe you can provide more realistic example of your query